# Filter by class name in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, filter, configuration, log4j2

I am using log4j2 and I don't know how I can filter by class name. I have tried with RegexFilter but it only filters the text message. In old log4j was enough with tag 'filter'

```
<filter class="aaaa.bbbb.cccc.ClassName">
```

Somebody knows how to do now?

Thank you in advance!

Update:

Ok, I did it! I need to define a logger and set the class name in attribute 'name':

```
<loggers>
    <logger name="aaaa.bbbb.cccc.ClassName" additivity="false" level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </logger>
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</loggers>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works automatically in Log4j if you follow the naming convention for loggers. In your code, declare loggers with their class name:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

The logger is automatically assigned the name `fully.qualified.class.name.of.MyClass`. Now, in your configuration you can use this *fully qualified name* (or the *package name* or the first part of the *package*) to do **filtering** and **routing**.

---

### Filtering

The below example shows how to filter log events based on the package of the class doing the logging: all `DEBUG` and `TRACE` level log events by classes in package `com.other.company` will be ignored, and for classes in package `com.another.project` only `ERROR` and `FATAL` logging will be included.

```
<Configuration status="warn">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/my.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>

    <!-- drops all DEBUG and TRACE logging done by any class in this package -->
    <Logger name="com.other.company" level="INFO" />

    <!-- log only ERROR and FATAL logging by classes in this package -->
    <Logger name="com.another.project" level="ERROR" />

    <!-- by default, all log events are written to MyFile -->
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

---

### Routing

The below example shows how to route log events to separate log files based on the package of the class doing the logging: all logging by classes in package `com.other.company` will not be written to `my.log` by only to `other.log`.

```
<Configuration status="warn">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/my.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
    </File>
    <File name="OtherFile" fileName="logs/other.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <!-- all logging from this package and subpackages goes to OtherFile -->
    <!-- Note: set additivity=false or logging will also go to the root logger -->
    <Logger name="com.other.company" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="OtherFile"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: If I specify additivity="false",the log could not written to OtherFile, while additivity="true",it will append to two files.

Comment: @remko-popma is there a way to achieve this routing programmatically?

Comment: Yes, take a look at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html